# Force Bash normal tab completion if intelligent completion fails

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Since tab completion became a standard feature in shells I have been a very happy user of it. I even like Bash's intelligent completion (where it only searches for PDF files, if I type evince foo<TAB>) - as long as it guesses correctly.

It ruins an otherwise happy day when Bash uses its intelligent completion to refuse completing.

Today I wanted to:

```
tar xvf centos5.8_x86_1.ova
```

So I entered:

```
tar xvf cent<TAB>
```

and Bash refuses to complete the path because .ova-files is not what you usually use with tar.

I know I can uninstall the bash-completion package to remove the intelligent completion. But can I have my cake and eat it too?

Can I ask bash to use intelligent completion first, and if that fails, then use non-intelligent completion?

Comment: <spam> Zsh can do it. </spam>

Answer (score 10):

The following should turn on normal bash completion after all 'intelligent'
completions have failed for the programs tar, vim and emacs:

```
compopt -o bashdefault tar vim emacs
```

see also the [relevant page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html) in the online bash manual.

Caveat: you get
the normal behavior for the type of completion (commands/filenames/usernames etc.) defined by the intelligent completion
for the command at hand, for example, the completion
for `service` will not complete filenames even if you call `complete -o bashdefault service`.

In this and other cases where the intelligent autocompletion fails,
you can always press `Alt-/` (or `M-/` in the bash manual's notation)
to complete *filenames* almost in the same way that TAB works if intelligent
completion is disabled (almost the same way in the sense that `M-/` does not complete patterns like `*.txt`).
See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Completion.html) for key sequences for other types of completions such as command and usernames.

Comment: Thanks for the Alt-/ mention, I had no idea that was in there

Answer (score 4):

Hej Ole :-),

Having your cake and eating it too:

`<tab>`will give you bash's best guess at completion. As you know, it is sometimes wrong.

However, `M-/` ( `ALT`+`SHIFT`+`7` (and that is left `ALT`, not the right `AltGr`) on our danish keyboards) will force completion as a file for when bash's completion is not perfect. So I use `M-/` when I know I want to force completion as a file.

For me, that is the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

bash completetion is an extension of bash's standard completion and is itself a bash program. So if you want to change how the program acts, just change it. This is free software, you are free to do it. For the specific case of the `tar` command, the file is `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/tar`. For `tar` to autocomplete a file with extension `ova`, just add it to the line

```
local tars='@(@(tar|gem|spkg)?(.@(Z|[gx]z|bz?(2)|lzma))|t@([glx]z|bz?(2)))'
```

so it says

```
local tars='@(@(tar|gem|spkg|ova)?(.@(Z|[gx]z|bz?(2)|lzma))|t@([glx]z|bz?(2)))'
```

Note that this is the path and the code existing for Debian Wheezy (current stable version). A different distro or version may have a different code but the idea is the same. Open the code and adjust it to do what you want it to do.

Edit: I just noticed that the question was about every time that it doesn't find a match and not only the specific case of adding `ova` to `tar`. Maybe it can still be useful to someone, to know where they can look for the source.

Comment: Modifying files in /usr that are owned by the package manager is a good way to induce a nasty shock on upgrade. Better: override the packaged configuration.

Comment: @ChrisDown and how would you do that? I'm still looking for the clean .bashrc solution.